# Kile: show me script example

Tags: kile, scripts

Can someone please show me an example script in Kile?

I want a example.

.

.

.

.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First things first. `:)`

According to [The Kile Handbook](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/extragear-office/kile/kile.pdf), chapter 13, "Kile's scripting feature allows for the execution of [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) code. Scripts can be managed
through the scripting panel in the sidebar." As a reference, both [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) are dialects of ECMAScript.

Unfortunately, my answer won't TeX-related. But here we go. `:)`

A quick look into the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) plus the *section 13.2* (API Reference) of *The Kile Handbook* made me come up with the following example:

1. I created a new script and called `myscript.js` with the content described as follows; Kile seems to save them in a specific scripts folder.

   ```
   var myCurrentDoc = (kile).currentTextDocument()
   var myName = (kile).getInputValue("Answer the question!", "What is your name?")
   myCurrentDoc.insertText("Hello " + myName)
   ```

   In line 1, I get a `KileTextDocument` object which reflects the currently active text document. Please note that my code has *no error checking!* In line 2, the `getInputValue` method opens a dialog with the given caption and label; the variable `myName` gets the returned value. In line 3, I simply insert the text.

   [image: Kile 1]
2. I saved the script and now it's available on the sidebar:

   [image: Kile 2]
3. Let's say I create a dummy `test.tex` file with the following content:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \begin{document}

   | % suppose the cursor is here.

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image: Kile 3]
4. Running the script:

   [image: Kile 4]
5. The result:

   [image: Kile 5]

   When clicking `OK`:

   [image: Kile 6]

There we go! My first script in Kile. `:)`

Take a look in the API Reference. It might have some useful methods, but beware! According to the handbook:

> Please note that the scripting API has not been finalized yet. The API described below might change in future versions of Kile.

Sorry to come up with this simple example, that's the only idea I had in such short time. `:)`

By the way: boas festas, amigo! `:)`

Comment: Perfect, this is already beginning to get me to touch it. Thank you. And Merry Christmas to you too.

Comment: Now, how to find (or locate) text (CTRL+F), using this method?

Comment: @Regis: Good question! I'm afraid there's no easy solution. `:(` Kile's scripting API seems to be promising, but as stated in the manual, it's under heavy development and likely to change in the future. IMHO the provided list of methods is quite limited. A possible workaround is to implement your own `find` method, that is, map the whole text to a data structure and manipulate lines and columns, and use one of Kile's methods to set the cursor position on-screen. I'm not sure if it's worth. As I see it, the scripting API provides just a basic interation experience. `:(`

Comment: But you did not say it gives to use javascript? Does it not to try this way?

Comment: @Regis: Yes, you can use JS, but IMHO the problem resides in the document interface provided by the Kile API. The available methods are scarce, so there's nothing much to do. JS can help a lot, but you are always bounded by the API. Of course, I'm not very well versed in JS, so maybe anyone else might come up with an answer to this particular issue. But my programmer intuition tells me there's nothing we can do unless hacking the API implementation itself.

Comment: sniff sniff sniff  :(

Comment: @Regis: I'm sorry. `:(` I've checked all the methods of the `KileTextDocument` object and the list is pretty much the same as the API reference. I was hoping to find undocumented methods but no luck. Those are the only methods you can play with. `:(`

Comment: Does anyone know if Kile might have a Python API or scripting interface in the future?  Or if another popular TeX editor has a Python API or scripting interface?

Comment: @user12711: IIRC TeXworks has a Python API, but that's as far as I can remember. `:)`